# Merge on multiple columns results in strange ordering

Tags: r, sorting, merge

When two data frames are merged by a numerical column then (by default) they are ordered by that column *as a number*.  However, if two numerical columns are used as the `by` then it results in a different ordering (in fact it seems as if the numerical columns are converted to strings and sorted as such).  Is this expected, or a bug?

For example, consider the following two data frames:

```
A <- data.frame(a = 1:12, b = 1, x = runif(12))
B <- data.frame(a = 1:12, b = 1, y = runif(12))
```

Then `merge(A, B, by = 'a')` results in a data frame with a column `a` with values 1, 2, ..., 9, 10, 11, 12 (i.e., the expected numerical ordering).  However `merge(A, B, by = c('a', 'b'))` results in a data frame with a column `a` with values 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, ..., 8, 9 (i.e., the same ordering as `sort(as.character(1:12))`).

Comment: Suppress the sort function within merge `merge(A, B, by = c('a', 'b'), sort=F)`

Comment: My questions turns out to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981849/numeric-column-ordered-incorrectly-on-merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's rather a feature than a bug of `merge`.

Inspection of the source code of `merge` showed that in the case when multiple columns are used for merging, the 'key' columns are internally combined into a vector by using `paste()`.

For example,  columns `a` and `b` from your data frame `A` will be represented by the string `"1\r1"  "2\r1"  "3\r1"  "4\r1"  "5\r1"  "6\r1"  "7\r1"  "8\r1"  "9\r1"  "10\r1" "11\r1" "12\r1"`.

`merge` uses this string to sort the resulting data frame, and that is how it ends up with the alphabetical ordering.

In the case when you merge only by one column, there is no need for using `paste`, and therefore sorting is performed by using the original type of the column.

Here is the relevant piece of the source code of `merge` (full text can be obtained by running `merge.data.frame` without parentheses in R console)

> ```
>     if (l.b == 1L) {
>         bx <- x[, by.x]
>         if (is.factor(bx)) 
>             bx <- as.character(bx)
>         by <- y[, by.y]
>         if (is.factor(by)) 
>             by <- as.character(by)
>     }
>     else {
>         if (!is.null(incomparables)) 
>             stop("'incomparables' is supported only for merging on a single column")
>         bx <- x[, by.x, drop = FALSE]
>         by <- y[, by.y, drop = FALSE]
>         names(bx) <- names(by) <- paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(bx)))
>         bz <- do.call("paste", c(rbind(bx, by), sep = "\r"))
>         bx <- bz[seq_len(nx)]
>         by <- bz[nx + seq_len(ny)]
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Your comments (and the source) explain the behavior completely.  I agree that perhaps it's not a bug in as much as the documentation for `merge` is not completely clear regarding what the behavior should be (help says "The rows are by default lexicographically sorted on the common columns").  However it seems to me that most people would expect the behavior that I expect.  Is it worth raising it as a bug/feature for R (or is something as basic as `merge` essentially frozen)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dplyr` package, we can get the following result

```
library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")

full_join(A, B, by=c("a", "b"))

     a b          x           y
    1   1 1 0.39907404 0.700782559
    2   2 1 0.84429488 0.600727090
    3   3 1 0.32232471 0.141495156
    4   4 1 0.74214210 0.262601640
    5   5 1 0.92944116 0.779255689
    6   6 1 0.10902661 0.001185645
    7   7 1 0.46336478 0.961711785
    8   8 1 0.58396008 0.211824751
    9   9 1 0.63126074 0.422233784
    10 10 1 0.09995935 0.179069642
    11 11 1 0.40832159 0.581116173
    12 12 1 0.48440814 0.004372634
```